Standard name for operation of type ('a list -> ('a -> 'b list) -> 'b list list) which distributes each element?
Is there a "standard" name or a generalized pattern for the following operation (written in OCaml with monadic let binding):
let rec combine (xs : 'a list) (f : 'a -> 'b list) : 'b list list =
  let open List.Let_syntax in
  match xs with
  | [] -> return []
  | x :: xs ->
      let%bind y = f x in
      let%bind ys = combine xs f in
      return (y :: ys)

It applies f to each element of xs and collects every possible combinations of the computation.
Thanks in advance!

If I had to give a name to what you do, I'd say you first map f, and then take the product of the result (as in this answer).

This is just traverse (it's always traverse). combine = flip traverse

@NaïmFavier Thanks a lot! This is indeed a special case for traverse.
